# CSS Syntax Highlighting doesn't work

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I have added the `<!-- lang-css -->` code to [CSS3Pie doesn't apply, instead border disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11527196/1520981) (in the edit queue currently), but the syntax-highlighting still doesn't work. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax is `<!-- language: lang-css -->`. Note the `language:` part there, see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). I've fixed that for you.

Note that normally your suggested edit stood the risk of being rejected for being too minor. Minor, quick syntax-formatting fix-only edits put an unnecessary strain on the suggested edits system, as 2 additional people need to review your edits before they are approved.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll accept as soon as possible!

Comment: I'm in no hurry. :-) Besides, others may have even better answers to give you.